# How to get last angle bracket of body tag regex, in HTML

Tags: html, regex, fiddler

Let's say I have a body tag with: `<body class="homehome mol-desktop aileron-font" id="home" itemid="/home/index.html" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CollectionPage">`

And I want to only get the last angle bracket `>` from the body tag, what kind of regex do I need for this?

The reason for this question is because I want to insert some code with Fiddler, but don't want to replace the insides of the body.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the body content itself, only the last angle bracket from the body.

Comment: You could use a lookbehind (if that's supported by your regex engine): `(?<=<[^>]*?)>`

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly when adding `(?<=<body[^>]*?)>`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, if you don't know the answer, please, don't bother.  You will not get it in `<body id="home"> this is the body<br>`  for example.  And the `.` matches all (including `>`, but it does not match an endline).